# Magento2.3: How to show the template file in a particular category page?

Tags: magento2.3, category, template, list

I have a custom module and on that I have a template file. I want to show that template in a particular category instead of it displaying in all the category pages.

How can I achieve that?

Anyone please suggest me to achieve this result?

Comment: You can use static block and call your custom template in this block after this static block select in particular category.

Comment: @PayalPatel, Could you please explain a little bit? As I have created a module and now the template file is displaying in all the categories

Comment: Can you please tell me that template file displaying in all categories or particular categories ?

Comment: Now, Its displaying all categories but I want to show that only for a particular category.

Comment: Ok got it, i will post answer in few times.

Comment: @Siva Check my answer just for your reference.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer as below, please check.

Answer (score 5):

For that, you just need to create one static block and call you `.phtml` file like the below example.

> {{block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
>   template="Vendor_Module::product/category_customdata.phtml"}}

Then you just need to call these blocks in a specific category. Check below image for your reference.

[image]

That's it.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Before I try your solution, I have to remove the template in all category page so I have removed layout from the module but still I can see the template file in category pages. How can I remove that template file in all category pages?

Comment: It's not related to this question. But, for that, I think you need to remove it manually.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Create CMS block

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="formblock" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}
```

> 2. In your category, set that CMS block.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load block with template with

catalog_category_view_id_[Cat Id].xml

Reference with similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451706/magento2-multiple-category-layouts?rq=1